# dynamically add and delete rows in a html table in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

[image: Add/Remove row in html Table using JavaScript]

I am a begginer in WordPress. I have made an html page using javasrcipt to add/remove row in html table. This html page works fine normally.
But when I copied it in WordPress it never responses. It doesn't let me add\remove rows.

Please help me with the WordPress code.

The code is below:

```js
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Timesheet Form</title>
    <script language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            //Column 1
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "button";
            var btnName = "button" + (rowCount + 1);
            element1.name = btnName;
            element1.setAttribute('value', 'Delete'); // or element1.value = "button";
            element1.onclick = function () { removeRow(btnName); }
            cell1.appendChild(element1);
            //Column 2  
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerhtml = rowCount + 1;
      //Column 3  
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.innerhtml = "Branch";
      
            //Column 4
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var element4 = document.createElement("input");
            element4.type = "text";
            cell4.appendChild(element4);
      
      //Column 5  
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            cell5.innerhtml = "Sem";
      
            //Column 6
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            var element6 = document.createElement("input");
            element6.type = "text";
            cell6.appendChild(element6);
      
      //Column 7  
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            cell7.innerhtml = "Subject";
      
            //Column 8
            var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
            var element8 = document.createElement("input");
            element8.type = "text";
            cell8.appendChild(element8);
      
      //Column 9  
            var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
            cell9.innerhtml = "Time From";
      
            //Column 10
            var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
            var element10 = document.createElement("input");
            element10.type = "text";
            cell10.appendChild(element10);
      
      //Column 11  
            var cell11 = row.insertCell(10);
            cell11.innerhtml = "Time To";
      
            //Column 12
            var cell12 = row.insertCell(11);
            var element12 = document.createElement("input");
            element12.type = "text";
            cell12.appendChild(element12);
        }
        
        function removeRow(btnName) {
            try {
                var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var rowObj = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if (rowObj.name == btnName) {
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <h3>Timesheet Form</h3>
    <body>
        <table  width="350px" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Your Name</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="nameTxt"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
        <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="button1" value="Delete" onClick="removeRow('button1')"></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Branch</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="branchTxt"></td><td>Sem</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="semTxt"></td>
                <td>Subject</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="subTxt"></td><td>Time From</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="timeFromTxt"></td>
                <td>Time To</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="timeToTxt"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't just paste HTML in WordPress and expect it to work. You need to use php, save to the database and from there get the results. Pasting html and javascript in post or a page won't work, because the contents get saved in the database, and the content is sanitized by default, which probably breaks your code.

Create a page template that outputs your table, then you can use that, or create a shortcode. There are numerous ways how to do that.

Comment: @dingo_d please tell me how to write the code for add dynamic rows in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't do the whole thing (SO is not a free do it for you place), but I can get you started.

Create `page-tables.php` in your theme and add

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Tables
*/

get_header();

$meta      = get_post_meta();
$name      = ( isset( $meta['nameTxt'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['nameTxt'][0] ) ? $meta['nameTxt'][0] : '';
$branch    = ( isset( $meta['branchTxt'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['branchTxt'][0] ) ? $meta['branchTxt'][0] : '';
$sem       = ( isset( $meta['semTxt'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['semTxt'][0] ) ? $meta['semTxt'][0] : '';
$subject   = ( isset( $meta['subTxt'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['subTxt'][0] ) ? $meta['subTxt'][0] : '';
$time_from = ( isset( $meta['timeFromTxt'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['timeFromTxt'][0] ) ? $meta['timeFromTxt'][0] : '';
$time_to   = ( isset( $meta['timeToTxt'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['timeToTxt'][0] ) ? $meta['timeToTxt'][0] : '';
?>

<table  width="350px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Your Name', 'your_theme_slug' ); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>" name="nameTxt">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" class="add_row_button" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Add Row', 'your_theme_slug' ); ?>"/>
<table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="delete_row_button" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Delete', 'your_theme_slug' ); ?>">
        </td>
        <td class="row_no">1</td>
        <td>
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Branch', 'your_theme_slug' ); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $branch ); ?>" name="branchTxt">
        </td>
        <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Sem', 'your_theme_slug' ); ?></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $sem ); ?>" name="semTxt">
        </td>
        <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Subject', 'your_theme_slug' ); ?></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $subject ); ?>" name="subTxt">
        </td>
        <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Time From', 'your_theme_slug' ); ?></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $time_from ); ?>" name="timeFromTxt">
        </td>
        <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Time To', 'your_theme_slug' ); ?></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $time_to ); ?>" name="timeToTxt">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php get_footer();
```

This will work for 1 table input only.

You can now go to your page, create a page and select 'Tables' page template which will show you your table.

What you need to do now is:

- Set up a save function so that the input values will save to the post meta
- Save all the values in a single meta, preferably as a json string that you can convert to array
- Read from the saved array and create a `foreach` loop with a single row - that way you'll go through all the values and output table row inside a `foreach`
- Enqueue JavaScript in a separate file (`custom.js` insdide a theme will do), that will add and delete rows, and all the saved values on button clicks.

Hope this helps.